# Why is the plot in matplotlib not continuous?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a dataset with solid lines in matplotlib, but it looks strange that it has not a single line instead multiple lines appear in the plot. With the dot marker there is no problem. For comparison the two plots are shown below. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

[image: line plot]
[image: dot plot]

Comment: It's hard to make meaningful analyses without seeing the data and code that causes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a couple of glitches in the data, manifested as zeros in the x-data. Log of zero goes to negative infinity. You can filter out the zeros with something like:

```
mask = x.astype(bool)
x = x[mask]
y = y[mask]
plt.semilogx(x, y)
```

Comment: hadn't noticed it was a log x scale; was wondering why they were going all the way over there. assuming this is true in this case sorting will just hide the problem: this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general this occurs when your points are not ordered sequentially.  Try sorting them first (this won't show on a scatter graph, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

I think your y variable is coded as a factor variable. You need to change it to a continuous scale. Check `pandas.to_numeric()`